# routerLinkActive directive causes undefined is not an object (evaluating 'router.events.subscribe')

Tags: angular, angular2-testing

I am using Angular2 RC3 and the new router. My HTML ...

```
<nav>
  <a [routerLink]="['/route1']" [routerLinkActive]="['active']">Route 1</a>
  <a [routerLink]="['/route2']" [routerLinkActive]="['active']">Route 2</a>
</nav>
```

routerLinkActive applies the 'active' class according to the selected link.
Works great.

Problem is by adding [routerLinkActive] my unit tests now fail with ...

> undefined is not an object (evaluating 'router.events.subscribe')

anyone got a fix for this?

many thanks

Comment: Hard to tell. It's not caused by the routerLinks above. Please show more code or try to reproduce in https://angular.io/resources/live-examples/quickstart/ts/plnkr.html

Comment: if i remove [routerLinkActive]="['active']" everything works fine

Comment: That might be. Because the `routerLink` directive injects the router and probably other things and when the router is not properly initialized or something else causes problems, this fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i put the tests on 'skip' in the end using Jasmine's xit

This is no longer a problem on ng2 final release